# Rendering properties based on checkboxes being selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have explained the issues in the comments of the CodeSandBox.
Basically I have an array of `field.names` that are being rendered with checkboxes. When each box is selected individual values for `lengthType` and `size` should be able to be entered by the user. As of now, the same values are being applied to each box that is checked.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fields: ["action", "callee", "caller", "duration", "message"],
      fieldNames: [],
      size: [],
      lengthType: []

    };
  }

  fieldNamesChanged = newFieldNames => {
    console.log(newFieldNames);
    this.setState({ fieldNames: newFieldNames });
  };

    onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log([e.target.name])
}

updateLengthType = (e) => {
    this.setState({ lengthType: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.lengthType)
}
  handleChange = event => {
    const schema = this.state.schemas.find(
      schema => schema.name === event.target.value
    );
    if (schema) {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `${schema.selfUri}`,
        headers: { Accept: "  " }
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.setState({
            fields: response.data.data.fields,
            selectedId: response.data.data.id
          });
          console.log(this.state.selectedId);
          console.log(this.state.fields);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
    }
  };
```

Example of fields array response from api call and rendering fields.name as the checkbox values

```
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "action",
        "dataType": "string",
    },
    {
        "name": "callee",
        "dataType": "string",
    },
    {
        "name": "caller",
        "dataType": "string",
    },
    {
        "name": "duration",
        "dataType": "double",
    },
    {
        "name": "message",
        "dataType": "string",
    },
]



  render() {
    const { fields, fieldNames } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Checkbox Group</h1>

        <div>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Choose field names</legend>
            <br />
            <CheckboxGroup
              checkboxDepth={5}
              name="fieldNames"
              value={this.state.fieldNames}
              onChange={this.fieldNamesChanged}
            >
              {fields &&
                fields.map(field => {
                  return (
                    <label>
                      <Checkbox value={field} />
                      {field}
                    </label>
                  );
                })}
              <br />
            </CheckboxGroup>

            <label>Length Type:</label>
            <select
              value={this.state.lengthType}
              onChange={this.updateLengthType}
              required
            >
              <option value="">Select Length Type...</option>
              <option value="fixed">Fixed</option>
              <option value="variable">Variable</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            <label>Size:</label>
            <input
              value={this.state.size}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="number"
              name="size"
              placeholder="1"
              min="0"
              required
            />
            <br />
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/7z0y46jw0q

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code and information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems I found

1. I don't see any `onChange` function which is supposed to handle your input for size.
2. Initial size state is not defined in constructor
3. Provide key props for child components

=====================

Update

I created a example

https://codesandbox.io/s/kkxv3nl7n5

I'm not so sure if this is what you are trying to do. See my sandbox link and check if it is what you are trying to do.

I thought if checkbox is checked then `lengthType, size` values for last checked checkbox should show. So, your `size, lengthType` state should be an **Object**. Because it will save your size and length type for each fieldName. So I changed it like below.

```
onChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    const { fieldNames } = this.state;
    const lastCheckedFieldName = fieldNames[fieldNames.length - 1];
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        size: {
          ...prevState.size,
          [lastCheckedFieldName]: e.target.value
        }
      };
    });
  };
```

And in the render function your input value is referencing `this.state.size` and i don't understand this at all because you said you wanted individual size for each field. That should be dynamically referencing to an object or array with a key that might be determined by state in order to seperate values for each field.

```
const lastCheckedFieldName = fieldNames[fieldNames.length - 1];

<input
      value={this.state.size[lastCheckedFieldName] || 1}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      type="number"
      name="size"
      placeholder="1"
      min="0"
      required
/>
```

Comment: I have an `onChange` for size and lengthType just didn't include in post. I'll update. Same case for `size` and `lengthType` in my constructor. And this really isn't an answer.

Comment: I'll update my answer if you update your question with full context

Comment: size state in constructor is an array but render function referencing it without key. Is it a not included thing in post too?

Comment: i made an update to my answer and a sandbox example please check and let me know if it works for you

Comment: That did the trick, but now the values being sent in the data request are incorrect. It's adding the first checkbox value to `lengthType` and `size`. `"data": 
 "{\"name\":\"QS7\",
 \"selectorField\":\"callee\",
 \"fields\":
  [{\"name\":\"action\",
  \"lengthType\":{\"action\":\"fixed\"},
  \"size\":{\"action\":\"3\"},
  \"maxArrayElements\":{\"action\":\"4\"}
  }]}"`. So there is something weird going on with how the values are being stored. I have updated the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j29yp2j905. I will open a new question, as it differs from the original one.

Comment: How is each `fieldName` and the properties (i.e `lengthType` and `size` being saved to state. Aren't they all being pushed into the same object array, how can they be sent separately in a post request?

Comment: Yes this is just an example. In the realworld people usually save them in array of object ,with much care about immutability

Comment: Well that is a concern of mine

Comment: Yes it is. You need an array of object way example?

Comment: I would most definitely.

Comment: I made few changes to example codesandbox. check it out